# Is it possible to run a file as soon as an HDMI device is plugged in?

Tags: windows, hdmi, autorun

Almost everybody knows that if a USB has an `autorun.inf` file, it will be executed so that other files automatically load. But I was wondering, if this is also possible for HDMI cables. So, if you plug in an HDMI, a certain (`.bat`, `.py` etc…) file will be executed, like a video file or maybe a browser.

I’m running Windows 10 and I always use my (non smart) TV for watching movies on a bigger screen. I’m not lazy, I just want to know whether it's possible or not.

Since storing files on an HDMI cable is, well, just impossible, this `autorun` file should probably be just a configuration thing in the settings, right? I’d prefer not to use any third-party tools or applications which are always running in the background, scanning for HDMI devices. But, if there aren't any other possibilities, I’ll probably have to use such a program.

**Edit:**
I should have added this: this `.bat` or `.py` is stored on the computer, so even when no HDMI devices are connected, this script can still be run.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `autorun.inf` is enjoying its well-deserved retirement nowadays. ;) Other than writing a program that permanently runs, I don't see any way this could be accomplished.

Comment: Someone competent in programming could make a program to do what you want, but is not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no depending on what you mean by “…when an HDMI device is plugged in?”

#### No, it’s not possible to run a file off of an HDMI device.

No, you cannot run a file from an HDMI connected device to the system it’s connected to.

While HDMI is a data cable—as opposed to VGA which would be an analog cable transmitting video signal—it does not have any data storage capabilities.

Devices that plug directly into an HDMI port—such as Google’s Chromecast or Intel’s Compute Stick—simply use the HDMI connection to send video and audio data to a connected device; there is no system level data storage or two-way transmission that would normally considered to be data storage and transmission happening there.

For example, [this question on the Information Security Stack Exchange site](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19007/21196) explores the theoretical possibilities of a system being infected via an HDMI cable. The general conclusion one gets from the discussion is while it is *theoretically possible* that a system could be infected via an HDMI connection but there is no proof of concept—or even an inkling of an idea—of how to do that.

#### Yes, it should be possible for your OS to detect if an HDMI cable is connected and do something based on that action.

That said, if you wanted to script the main computer system’s OS to detect if an HDMI device has been connected and then do something based on that action, that *should be* possible but as how to script that is really idiosyncratic to whatever OS you would attempt to do something like that on.

Comment: So you are saying NO? Although informational it does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe, I should have been clearer, but what about a file that's stored on the computer itself? So when plugged in, that file (on the PC) is executed?

Comment: Exactly! Do you maybe happen to know what kind of script this would be? If not, don't worry, maybe someone else knows.

Comment: @PythonPupil1906, that's a question for Stack Overflow.  It would be off-topic here.

Comment: @fixer1234 True, I'll post that question there as soon as I can! Anyway, thank you all for your time!

Comment: Obligatory nitpick: VGA also has DDC. :D Of course, HDMI has a lot more with Ethernet and whatnot. Still, a VGA signal is as “data” as it gets. It’s just analog vs digital.